# I want to use a common method for n similar charts. My barrier is to write the chart name dynamically over a variable. How can I do this?

Tags: c#, charts, controls

I have to use several charts in my C# form app. Each chart shall visualize a measuring curve of the related test-step. There is no fix defined amount of test steps. (2…16).

Normaly I would write n times the same chart drwaing method , just with different chart names (Chart1,Chart2....)

In order to shorten my code, I want to call always the same chart drawing method with the "step_no" input parameter. But the problem is that I cannot declare the chart control's name (Chart1, Chart2, Chart3…Chartn) over my step no.

How can I use one method with input parameter “step no”, that will draw the related chart(n)?

Here is my actual method where I draw the chart1. But my main barrier is, that I don't know how to write the chart name over a variable.

```
public void Draw_Chart(int step_no)
{
    chart1.Series.Clear();
    chart1.Titles.Clear();
    chart1.Legends.Clear();
    var newSeries_1 = new Series();
    var newSeries_2 = new Series();
    newSeries_1.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
    newSeries_2.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
    chart1.Series.Add(newSeries_1);
    chart1.Series.Add(newSeries_2);
    List_X_Axis.Clear();

    for (int w = 0 ; w <= 940; w++)
    {
        parameter_value_chartX[w] = w;
        //parameter_value_chartY1[w] = 150;
        //parameter_value_chartY1[w] = 250;
    }
        
    newSeries_1.Points.DataBindXY(parameter_value_chartX, parameter_value_chartY1);
    newSeries_2.Points.DataBindXY(parameter_value_chartX, parameter_value_chartY2);

    chart1.BackColor = Color.Gray;
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Title = ".";
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Title = "mm";
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.TitleForeColor = Color.Cyan;
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.LabelStyle.ForeColor = Color.Cyan;
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = 0d;
    chart1.Series[0].Color = Color.Cyan;
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Minimum = cur_scale_min;
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum = cur_scale_max;
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY2.Enabled = AxisEnabled.True;
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY2.Minimum = pos_scale_min;
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY2.Maximum = pos_scale_max;
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY2.Title = "% of Max. Current";
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY2.TitleForeColor = Color.Yellow;
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY2.LabelStyle.ForeColor = Color.Yellow;
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY2.MajorGrid.LineColor = Color.Silver;
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY2.MajorTickMark.LineColor = Color.Silver;
    chart1.Series[1].YAxisType = AxisType.Secondary;
    chart1.Series[1].Color = Color.Yellow;
}
```

Comment: if i got your question right, you can store the chart controls in an array and then reference the chart in the array, using the step number as the index.

Comment: @hakim00  I have to draw n Charts in my form, step by step. So normaly I would use my chart method n times for each chart. But I want to shorten my code and want to use just one method. Here my barrier is to address the chart name indirectly over a variable. I think your suggestion is for one chart with n chart value-arrays. That is not I what I want.